# What is the purpose of 1px <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Has anyone an idea what bright idea may lie behind placing 1px image inside different html blocks? They are used in Shoper webstore (SaaS) themes in many different places like those below. I need to reduce nodes count for SEO sake and I'm tempted to remove them (they are in hundreds or thousands on single page).

Default CSS is:

```css
.px1 {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and I haven't analyzed it against JS code modification, only with RWD (nothing is changing).

HTML examples:

```html
<button class="addtobasket btn btn-red" type="submit">
    <img src="/libraries/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    <span>Buy</span>
</button>
```

```html
<div class="boxhead">
    <span>
        <img src="/libraries/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
        Sale
    </span>
</div>
```

```html
<li class="parent" id="hcategory_126">
    <h3>
        <a href="/pl/c/bikes/126" title="Bikes" id="headercategory126" class="spanhover">
            <span>Bikes</span>
            <img src="/libraries/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
        </a>
    </h3>                                                                                                    
    <div class="submenu level2">...</div>
</li>
```

Comment: A tracking pixel?

Comment: It's guesswork without context, but a transparent 1px gif can be used as a placeholder for the src attribute of an image which then can be swapped out for the real src later on in JS - when the image is in the viewport. Some libraries used to do that to achieve "lazy loading" of images. This was prior to browsers supporting the `loading="lazy"` attribute. Again... just a guess.

Comment: @VLAZ This was my guess too, but thousands on single page in such different places like menu, Headings, buttons and with `display: none`? That would be insane...

Comment: I always heard them called "image beacons"...